# Detect which UIBarButton was tapped from other ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have 4 UIBarButtons which show PopoverController when tapped. Depending upon which button tapped, I have to show different popover content and this has to be done in PopoverController viewDidLoad method.

Here is how I am handling popover from which UIBarButton tapped. in (VC1.m)

```
[PopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems count] -1]
                                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                 animated:YES];
```

I want to put condition in viewDidLoad, (PopoverController.m)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   if ([super.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems count] -1]) {
      // Trigger method# 1
    }
    else {
      // Trigger method# 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about just making this an argument to a custom `init:` method on your PopoverController?   That way you set it the `-viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: Thanks gaige. No I havent thought about that. can you please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a property for the initial tab state that you are going to be using.   basically:

```
@property NSInteger tabState;
```

Then you can either set this right after initialization, or in the init function.

Assuming that `PopoverController` in your code above is a subclass of `UIPopoverController` which you are instantiating somewhere, you can either change the init function (usually `– initWithContentViewController:` to `– initWithContentViewController:tabState:` and then pass the tab state in during the your call to init:

```
– initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc tabState:(NSInteger)newTabState
{
     self = [super initWithContentViewController: vc];
     if (self) {
         self.tabState = newTabState;
     }
     return self;
}
```

Then in your `-viewDidLoad` method, you can just trigger off of your `self.tabState` and you have the state information without the tight binding to the prior view.

Comment: Apparently my code has initwithContentViewController but PopoverController is not subclass of PopoverController and hence i can not put a method there. Where else can i put the custom method?

Comment: You can always just add the property to your class and set it after you create the instance.  That's also mentioned in my original answer.